# LIKE com explode PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Boa noite consagrados, tenho uma pagina de busca, na qual quero que quando alguem pesquisar algo como "i3 memoria gabinete tela" apareça todos os items disponiveis na tabela com relacao a estes items pesquisados, pra isso devo utilizar o explode na variavel que recupera os valores e colocar no LIKE, o problema esta ai, ele cria um array, que nao tenho como saber quantos valores ira ter dependendo com a pesquisa do usuario, se eu colocar    LIKE '$variavel[0]'  ele vai e mesmo sem o 0, mas retorna apenas o primeiro valor digitado, gostaria de saber se ter uma forma de puxar os outros de modo que nao puxe a tabela toda devido a um array vazio.
Segue o Codigo:

```
<?php        
$buscaexp = explode(" ",$buscanaurl);
$procura = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%$buscaexp[0]%' OR (nome LIKE '%$buscanaurl%')");
    $procura->execute();
?>
```

segue link pra quem quiser olhar http://www.tcc2016.96.lt/busca?busca=memoria+exemplo+i3

Comment: os links de duplicada de certa forma me ajudaram um pouco, no entanto ainda nao consegui fazer funcionar, talvez pelo fato de ser PDO precisa de algo que ainda nao sei o que é

Comment: está assim:     for($i = 0; $i < count($buscaexp); $i++) 
   $param = "nome LIKE '%".$buscaexp[$i]."%'";
   
  
  //var_dump($buscaexp);
  $procura = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE ".$param);  
  $procura->execute();var_dump($procura);

Comment: e na saida do var_dump esta assim: object(PDOStatement)#1 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(45) "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%i3%'" } mesmo quando eu pesquiso por mais de um produto na barra é como se ele buscasse apenas relacionado ao ultimo array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi

Tenta checkar se existe valor na posição [0]

isset(array[0])

caso true, adicione entao na string de consulta

Comment: entao amigo meu problema maior mesmo é no 0 do $buscaexp[0] porque ali ta especificando q é pra consultar apenas a primeira string, eu preciso que algo identifique quantas strings tem e faça a pesquisa em cada uma delas

Comment: sim existe valor na posicao 0, se eu colocar "memoria ddr2" havera na posicao 0 e na 1, o que preciso e que mostre resultados relacionados tanto com o 0 quanto o 1 e assim por diante se existir

Comment: o isset funcionou muito obrigado pela dica.